# How do I make the key values that equal number argument appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to return the keys thats have as many duplicates as the number argument but it isn't working

```
    def duplicate_count(text, number):
            count = {}
            sen = str(text)
            for  spot in sen.lower():
                 count.setdefault(spot,0)
                 count[spot] = count[spot] +1
           return  count.keys == number
```

Comment: Not working like how? What's going wrong? How does the actual output differ from your expectations?

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter` to count occurrences. Your return value is wrong, try printing out the values in those variables to see what you're comparing.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the return value to this:

`return [i for i in count if count[i] >= number]`

This list comprehension creates a list that includes keys in `counts` that have a value greater or equal to `number`.

So the full method will look like this:

```
def duplicate_count(text, number):
    count = {}
    sen = str(text)
    for  spot in sen.lower():
         count.setdefault(spot,0)
         count[spot] = count[spot] +1
    return [i for i in count if count[i] >= number]

duplicate_count('aaaassddd', 3) # returns ['a', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need something like this:

```
def duplicate_count(text, number):
    a = str(text).lower()
    return  {i:a.count(i) for i in set(a) if a.count(i)==number}

duplicate_count("hhhaaafggggg",3)
{'h': 3, 'a': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `collections.Counter`, e.g.

```
[k for k, v in ct.Counter(str(text).lower()).items() if v >= n]
```

**Code**

More generally, you can count both upper- and lowercase strings using a flag:

```
import collections as ct


def replicates(text, n=2, case_sensitive=False):
    """Return strings with counts >= n."""
    s = str(text) if case_sensitive else str(text).lower()
    return [k for k, v in ct.Counter(s).items() if v >= n]
```

Assuming you mean more than two repeated values, we used the term *replicates*.

**Demo**

```
replicates("aaaaabbcddd", 3)
# ['a', 'd']

replicates("AAaAabbcDdd", 3, True)
# ['A']
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic solution is to use `collections.Counter`, then filter with a list comprehension. You can also use 3rd party NumPy, which performs the filtering part more efficiently via vectorised operations:

```
import numpy as np

def replicates(text, n=3):
    values, counts = np.unique(list(text), return_counts=True)
    return values[counts==n]

res = replicates('aaaeabbecddde')

print(res)

array(['d', 'e'], dtype='<U1')
```